# Oracle SQL: Adding Case When inside UTL Match

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, case-when

I am using UTL matching to retrieve the values matching from two different tables and how similar they are. I am filtering by those who are at least 90 out of 100 similars so I can manually check if those values actually are the same or not.

As the resulting data is too big I am working on some new queries to take out those values who are surely the same value and does not need any manual checking. Like those >90% similar with a size of 9 characters.

**In order to do those I have just been using WHERE CLAUSE, but now I want to insert a CASE STATEMENT** as I want to state that those values that contain the word "University" and does not have a 95% similarity should not appear.

**The code I am using seem to be running but It's taking a lot of time. Would you know if it can be improved (for time)**. Thank you!!!

The code I am using will be like:

```
with consolidate_table as (....)

select
column1, column2,
UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(column1, column2) as jws
from consolidate_table

where UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(column1, column2) >= 90
AND UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(column1, column2) < 100
AND LENGTH (column1) <9
AND column1 = (CASE
    WHEN column1 LIKE '%University%' 
    AND UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(column1, column2) > 94
    THEN column1 ELSE NULL
    END)

;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure without sample data & expected results.

But at a first glace it can be simplified.

Using a `BETWEEN` the function is only called once.
And filtering those that are equal could help speed it up.

```
...
WHERE column1 <> column2
  AND UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity(column1, column2) BETWEEN (CASE WHEN column1 LIKE '%University%' THEN 95 ELSE 91 END) AND 99
```

Comment: But that would return only the values containing university. I need the rest too. It's about adding a condition; that whenever it finds a value containing the word University and a similarity bigger than 95. It should not show it